# How to send & consume Object in Spring AMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, config, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to send and consume the custom object as below using Spring AMQP.

Producer code

Record record = new Record("message1", new Date());
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(record);

Can anyone provide spring amqp @configuration settings for sending and consuming messages as above. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Sample Applications](http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/sample-apps.html); some of them use `@Configuration`.

But, essentially, you need...

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
            new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
    MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(myListener());
    container.setMessageListener(adapter);
    container.setQueues(foo());
    return container;
}

@Bean
public Object myListener() {
    return new Foo();
}
```

and the listener can be a POJO...

```
public class Foo {

    public void handleMessage(Record foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

[I added a Gist here](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/c86d22f6e00a526aec37) for XML version.

Comment: Thanks Russell, able to consume the Objects.\

Comment: I would love to see an example using XML config. I've got everything working and can send/receive strings, but not objects.

I can send objects, but they are never received by the app. Rabbit MQs CPU jumps to 100% after sending 1 message and stays at 100% untill I drop the queue, so it is kind of stuck.

Comment: See [this gist for an XML version](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/c86d22f6e00a526aec37)